# How can I make a block align with a textblock?

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

I am trying to make a poster with beamerposter. I am using the textpos package to position textblocks on the poster. Inside the textblock I am using block to get a title and a list of items with a custom colour scheme. However, the block does not align with the textblock. I am using the showboxes option to show the outline of the textblock and the eso-pic package to help me with positioning and it shows that the block is shifted down and to the left.

```latex
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[showboxes,absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\usepackage[texcoord,grid,gridunit=mm,gridcolor=red!50,subgridcolor=green!50]{eso-pic}

\usepackage[size=a1,orientation=landscape,scale=1.8]{beamerposter}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[shadow=false]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]

\definecolor{Aquamarine}{rgb}{0.5,1.0,0.83}
\definecolor{Gainsboro}{rgb}{0.86,0.86,0.86}
\definecolor{Black}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=Black,bg=Aquamarine}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=Gainsboro,fg=Black}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=Black}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=Black}

\usefonttheme{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

\begin{textblock*}{200mm}(100mm,100mm)
    \begin{block}{
        \centering
        \textbf{The block title}
          }
    \begin{itemize}
        \item some text
        \item more text
        \item even more text

    \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
\end{textblock*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: code output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround to my problem by using tcolorbox instead of blocks:

```latex
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[showboxes,absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\usepackage{tcolorbox} %use this instead of blocks

\usepackage[texcoord,grid,gridunit=mm,gridcolor=red!50,subgridcolor=green!50]{eso-pic}

\usepackage[size=a1,orientation=landscape,scale=1.8]{beamerposter}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[shadow=false]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]

\definecolor{Aquamarine}{rgb}{0.5,1.0,0.83}
\definecolor{Gainsboro}{rgb}{0.86,0.86,0.86}
\definecolor{Black}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=Black,bg=Aquamarine}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=Gainsboro,fg=Black}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=Black}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=Black}

\usefonttheme{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

\begin{textblock*}{200mm}(100mm,100mm)
    \begin{block}{
        \centering
        \textbf{Normal block}
          }
    \begin{itemize}
        \item has horizontal offset
        \item more text
        \item even more text

    \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{200mm}(100mm,200mm)
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    \centering
    \textbf{tcolorbox}
    \tcblower
    \begin{itemize}
        \item no horizontal offset 
        \item more text
        \item even more text

    \end{itemize}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{textblock*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The tcolorbox is horizontally aligned with the textblock. Now I just need to work out how to set the colour scheme the way I want...

Answer (score 0):

When I compile your code I get a different result from your. The bloch is centered with an horizontal offset (left and right). Have you update to the last version of textpos?[image]

Comment: I'm using an online editor (overleaf.com), so I'm not sure what version of textpos they are using. But even if I switch to the latest version of textpos, is there any way to get rid of the horizontal offset?

Comment: @user28719 I find that using `\TPMargin{1ex}` adjust the block inside the textblock, but add a vertical space inside the block.